# How can we address the error associated with estimators in linear regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am dealing with a noisy dataset that has a certain amount of error for every estimator. Say, xi's are plus/minus a constant.
I am wondering if there is a way to handle these errors or at least see their effect on the resulting regressed line.

Comment: If your *x* variables have errors your OLS estimates will be biased. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models for example, and questions with the tag [`errors-in-variables`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/errors-in-variables). You might also get some value from searches related to *model II regression*.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you soo much. You have no idea how invaluable your comment was. Do you know a good source with an example for EIV? I am currently reading "Total least squares and errors-in-variables modeling: analysis, algorithms and applications" book.

Comment: If that was useful to you I could make it into an answer. I am sorry, I don't know of a good source for it off-hand; it's a very long time since I did anything on it. If you prefer you could consider modifying your question to ask about that.

Comment: @Glen_b that was more than useful. I would happily mark that as an answer to my question. However, by reading more about it I figured my problem is somewhere else. I am posting another question in that regard now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your $x$ variables (predictors, features, IVs) have errors, the ordinary least squares estimators will be biased.

[This assumes that the x's the y's are based on are the 'true' without-error x's, $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\epsilon$ but we only observe $x^o=x+\eta$]

[image: plot of errors-in-variables data for the simple regression case]

Above is a plot of some 'true' $x$ (blue) and observed $x$ with error (orange) with the fitted least squares lines for each (the population line is dashed in red but visually coincident with the blue line in the lower/left half of the plot. In this example the error in the $x$ is about the same size as the error in the $y$, and this increase in the variation of $x$ "spreads" the points out, flattening the ordinary least squares estimate a little (it's small because the variance of the observation error in $x$ is small relative to the variance of $x$).

We see some indication of the 'attenuation' effect (bias toward $0$) that is seen with simple-regression if one uses least squares on such data.

In multiple regression the bias is not necessarily toward 0 but that is the more usual situation.

For additional information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models and questions with the tag [`errors-in-variables`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/errors-in-variables). You might also get some value from searches related to *model II regression*.